# Spring-MVC: Broken pipes causes thread locks

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

We use tomcat 7 with Spring 4.2.5 and Spring-MVC. We have several REST interfaces that some of our customers can also call. Recently we included jackson XML (from fasterxml) so XML interfaces could be handled with jackson instead of JAXB. Since then after a tomcat restart the CPU load grows more and more as time goes on, resulting in 100% CPU load after a few hours.

We were able to pinpoint the cause to one particular REST XML POST interface that one of our customers calls frequently. We also were able to observe that such requests fail with a HTTP 499 ClientClosedRequest error. The number of those 499 coincides with the number of locked threads that we retrieved via kill -3.

The stacktrace of those locked threads looks like this:

```
"catalina-exec-1" #50 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f11c0001800 nid=0x1d89 runnable [0x00007f11f46e6000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at com.sun.xml.stream.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:353)
at com.sun.xml.stream.XMLReaderImpl.next(XMLReaderImpl.java:565)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlFactory._initializeXmlReader(XmlFactory.java:653)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlFactory._createParser(XmlFactory.java:536)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlFactory._createParser(XmlFactory.java:29)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.createParser(JsonFactory.java:820)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3084)
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:222)
at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:209)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:197)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:147)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:125)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:99)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:161)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:817)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:731)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
```

We were unable to reproduce this with our own requests. We even tried to provoke a 499 error by aborting our requests prematurely, but to no avail.
Even if we were to reproduce this - how could we actually fix this, since Spring and Jackson are doing all the work.

It is unfortunately impossible to go back to JAXB since some of our new features rely on jackson.

Comment: Check if you can log the http requests as they arrive, in the way it is described here: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-http-logging. In this way you will be able to see the content of the failing requests, and even copy it to reproduce for debugging purposes.

Comment: We already did something like that. The requests were all normal and we were not able to reproduce it this way. The HTTP 499 errors cannot be reproduced that way and we believe that those are the core of the issue.

Comment: If your client calls the service from a browser using Ajax, then the problem is possible to come from an antivirus plugin on the browser. Otherwise, probably you should investigate the infrastructure between your server and your client's server (e.g. load balancers, proxies).

Comment: Since these kind of connection issues can always occur with any client, any network connection and any software, we think it'll be much more usefull to fix the problem in our software.